# Add padding to Formatted Object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, formatting, padding

In vb.net is it possible to add padding to an object that has been formatted as currency? I want all of my variables in a loop to appear evenly spaced in a listbox, but when I try:

```
FormatCurrency(dblexample).ToString.PadLeft(4, " ")
```

It does not pad it at all.

Comment: Please show the code where you are adding these strings to the ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because the ListBox control automatically removes leading and trailing spaces.
Instead, set the ListBox's column values so that they're evenly spaced. There may be a property that makes columns evenly spaced.

I've found this to be true when working on other projects involving the ListBox control.